# inserting rows and maintaining formula in all rows

Tags: windows, excel

I have a  simple formula to average a series of 10 numbers  =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C1:L1")).  When I try to insert a new row, the formula for the subsequent rows do not change and data is all in error.  Example;  Insert new row before row 4.  Old row 4 becomes row 5, but formula for data in 5 stays =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C4:L4")) and I want it to automatically change to ("C5:L5"). I'm new to excel and have tried several sites to figure this out to no avail.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need to use INDIRECT here?  If you remove this, problem should be solved.

```
=average(c4:l4)
```

The Microsoft documentation provides a reasonable definition and example.

As a real-world example, suppose that in column A I list different types of cars and in columns B, C, D and so on I am listing characteristics of these cars which are taken from different sheets.  Assume that the sheet name and what is in column A are the same, e.g. "Ford".

If I wanted to take value of cell B2 on the Ford sheet, and A2 was equal to Ford I could type 
=indirect(a2&"!b2") instead of ='Ford'!b2.

Comment: Give some example/explanation on INDIRECT, so that it would be helpful for others.